# Understanding Kotlin enum converter

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, enums, type-conversion

i have following kotlin code, made by guy who is nowhere to be found anymore...

Enum class:

```
enum class CodeType(val code: Long) {
    UNDEFINED(0), A(1), B(2), C(3), D(4);

    companion object {
        private val values = values()
        fun getByDbCode(dbCode: Long) = values.firstOrNull { it.code == dbCode }
    }
}
```

Converter class ?

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
class CodeTypeEnumConverter : AttributeConverter<CodeType, Long> {
    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbCode: Long?): CodeType? {
        return if (dbCode == null) {
            null
        } else CodeType.getByDbCode(dbCode)
    }

    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(type: CodeType): Long? {
        return type.code
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "XXXX", name = "YYYY")
data class Code (
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long?,
            @Column(name = "CUSTOMERID")
        var customerId: String,
            @Column(name = "CODE")
        var code: String,
            @Column(name = "CODETYPE")
        @Convert(converter = CodeTypeEnumConverter::class)
        var codeType: CodeType,
            @Column(name = "COUNTRYCODE")
        var countryCode: String,
            @Column(name = "BEGINDATE")
        var beginDate: LocalDate?,
            @Column(name = "ENDDATE")
        var endDate: LocalDate?,
)
```

I've done some work with kotlin, and somewhat understand it. But this is something i dont get..

Im supposed to save new instance of this entity to DB.
But db column does not take CodeType as a value, but instead `Long` value 0-3.

As i understand, this `@converter` system should covert CodeType -> Long but i dont think it does.. All i get is error when saving.

However same entity is used for getting info from same table in the first place, so converter seems to work for getting info from database but not for saving.

Why ? how would i fix this ?

I could circumvent this with second entity and mapper, but thats quite ugly solution i think.

EDIT:

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
```

And

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17068, SQLState: 99999
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid argument(s) in call
```

Comment: What type of error are you getting? Can you provide Logcat output?

Comment: `Converter` is part of Hibernate, not related to Kotlin. And it looks fine. Error is a generic Oracle error. How exactly are you saving the entity?